# How to pass a cell's address into Range to change the color of the cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to make a function where I can enter a value and a range of cells to compare the value against.

When the value is equal to the cell value, I want to change the color of the cell.

My attempt is to get the address of a cell and pass it into Range().

Code I found for changing color:

```vb
Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(255,255,255)
```

Using this code works, but need to predefine the address:

```vb
Sub ColorChange()
    Dim a As String
    a = "B2"
    Range(a).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End Sub
```

Using it as a function with arguments does not work:

```vb
Function FindMultiple(var As Integer, argv1 As Range)

    Dim c As Variant
    Dim cAddress As String
    
    For Each c In argv1
        If c = var Then
            cAddress = c.Address
            Range(cAddress).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End If
    Next c

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't try to format cells with UDF. 

_Microsoft documentation:_

> [Description of limitations of custom functions in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

You can use conditional format to get the expected result.

Comment: `If c = var Then c.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)`  but as noted that will not work if you're calling the function from a worksheet.

Comment: I think this is best achieved by 'Conditional Formatting'; not a VBA worksheet function. It can be done as a VBA Sub, but you need to have something calling it (like Selection Change event: whenever a value in the range changes, or a button user clicks.)

Answer (score 1):

This will work as a UDF but likely not "recommended" since you're doing an end-run around the UDF limitations imposed in Excel...

```
'UDF to set cell fill based on value
Function FindMultiple(var As Integer, argv1 As Range)
    Dim c As Variant, clr As Long, cmd, ws As String
    ws = argv1.Parent.Name
    cmd = "SetColor(""" & ws & """,""" & argv1.Address & """,-1)"
    Application.Run cmd   'clear existing fill
    For Each c In argv1.Cells
        If c.Value = var Then
            'fill if matched
            cmd = "SetColor(""" & ws & """,""" & c.Address & """," & RGB(255, 255, 0) & ")"
            Application.Run cmd
        End If
    Next c
End Function

'this just sets the cell fill color
Function SetColor(wsName, addr, clr)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName).Range(addr)
        If clr >= 0 Then
            .Interior.color = clr         'set a fill
        Else
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'clear the fill
        End If
    End With
End Function
```